# Eager evaluation of lambdas within a list comprehension

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

Consider a python function:

```
def testSetsFromStrings(tt):
  x1= [lambda x: x.split(' ') for t in tt]
  return x1
```

Let's invoke it with the following :

```
tt = ['id0 id1 id2 id3 id4', 
'id10 id11 id12 id13 id14', 
'id20 id21 id22 id23 id24', 
' id30 id31 id32 id33 id34', 
'id50 id51 id52 id53 id54']

testSetFromStrings(tt)
```

A breakpoint was placed after  the `x1= ..` line and we can see `x1` =

```
<class 'list'>: [<function testSetsFromStrings.<locals>.<listcomp>.
<lambda> at 0x11cee5730>, <function testSetsFromStrings.<locals>.<listcomp>.
<lambda> at 0x11cee5840>, <function testSetsFromStrings.<locals>.<listcomp>.
<lambda> at 0x11cee58c8>, <function testSetsFromStrings.<locals>.<listcomp>.
<lambda> at 0x11cee5950>, <function testSetsFromStrings.<locals>.<listcomp>.
<lambda> at 0x11cee59d8>]
```

I am at a loss as to how to cause that `lambda` to be *eagerly* evaluated. What can be done here?

** Update**

The logic shown is a simplification of the multi step function that is needed: to focus on just the mechanics of invoking a lambda.  Replacing the `lambda` with directly invoking `split` does not address the real need.

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: this should work without a function or unnecessary lambda `[x.split(' ') for x in tt]`

Comment: If you think about that comprehension (*for each x in tt, return a new lambda...*) it should make sense to you why you are seeing what you are seeing...

Comment: @dawg Maybe so but I'm not sure how to structure this to get the result of evaluting a lambda or function.

Comment: So you want to apply several functions to an iterable?

Comment: As it is, your code does not do anything useful, so it's difficult for us to tell what is the better way to do it. As it is, values in `tt` are completely ignored and you just get a bunch of lambdas which all do the same thing. What do you want the code to do?

Comment: The standalone `lambda x: x.split(' ')` only defines a lambda function; it does not call the lambda function. Either use `map` to define a callable and call it in one step or defined the function or lambda externally from the list comprehension.

Comment: @dawg Ya thx - i got that from the accepted answer

Comment: It's odd that `x` is used for 2 different purposes -- lambda argument and iteration variable. If then intention was to capture ephemeral value of comprehension `x` in a lambda, then it's not trivial: instead of `[lambda: x**2 for x in range(3)]  # (=> 4,4,4)` something like `[functools.partial(lambda y=None: y**2, y=x) for x in range(3)]  # (=> 0, 1, 4)` is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you don't want lambdas at all?  Is this what you want?

```
def testSetsFromStrings(tt):
    x1 = [x.split(' ') for x in tt]
    return x1
```

Lambdas are functions: they are evaluated when you call them.  If you want them to run immediately, then you probably don't need a lambda at all.

If you need to invoke a function, then invoke it:

```
def testSetsFromStrings(tt):
    x1 = [my_function(x) for x in tt]
    return x1
```

Comment: Well I had a function in place of the lambda earlier .. I want to be able to invoke either a function or a lambda. The logic shown is a much simpler representation of what I want to do - to just ask about how to invoke a lambda or function.

Comment: You'll need to explain your full situation then.

Comment: Updated the OP.  If necessary i'll convert the `lambda` to a multi-step function which includes statements (such as `print`) to illustrate that I really do need the original question answered.

Comment: I've updated my answer: invoke a function if you need to.

Comment: ok - so a `lambda` simply does not make sense/work here; it's either a direct application of the logic or invoke a _function_.   That's an acceptable explanation. I'll accept this answer after the requisite few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining the function, but not applying any arguments to it:

Try this instead

```
x1 = [(lambda x: x.split(' '))(x) for x in tt]
```

But it would be better to just extract the function definition outside of the comprehension if the function is at all complicated and then use a map or list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a map function instead of a list comprehension:

```
x1 = map(lambda x: x.split(' '), tt)
```

if you prefer the lamda function being present. Elsewhere just:

```
x1 = [x.split(' ') for x in tt]
```

as mentioned from others as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand is that lambdas are inherently functions themselves. Therefore, create a lambda function and invoke that.

```
testSetsFromStrings = lambda x: x.split(' ')
x1 = [testSetsFromStrings(t) for t in tt]
```